# Finding sum of coefficients in an exponential function

Tags: permutations, exponential-function

I came across a problem in which we had to find the general formula for the number of positive integers of n digits chosen from set (2,3,7,9) which are divisible by 3.

I figured out that any number of n digits from the set can be represented by
$(x^2+x^3+x^7+x^9)^{n}$. So in this I will have to find the sum of coefficients of $x^{3k}$ where k is a natural number but I have no idea how?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please use mathjax.....

Comment: A number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by $3$.  You will find that given the first $n-1$ digits there is either going to be a single choice for the final digit which makes it a multiple of $3$ if the previous $n-1$ digits didn't already form a multiple of $3$, or there will be two choices if it did.  This leads to a convenient recurrence relation which leads to a closed form.

Comment: Thanks but the closed form given is $(4^n+2)/3$ and I don’t see that coming. Could you please elaborate on your solution ?

Comment: If you want to find the sum of coefficients on $x^{3k}$, you can plug $1, \omega, \omega^2$ into the expression and sum, then divide by 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number is divisible by $3$ if and only if the sum of the digits is divisible by $3$.

There are $4^n$ different $n$-digit numbers you can make if you don't care about divisibility requirements.

An $n$-digit number who is divisible by $3$ made from these digits will either be a $2$ or $7$ attached to the end of an $n-1$ digit number who was *not* divisible by $3$ in which case exactly one of them would have made the resulting number divisible by $3$, or will have been a $3$ or $9$ attached to the end of an $n-1$ digit number who was already a multiple of $3$.

Letting $a(n)$ represent the number of $n$-digit numbers made from these digits who *are* divisible by $3$, the previous observations imply the following recurrence relation:

$$a(1)=2\\ a(n) = (4^{n-1}-a(n-1)) + 2\cdot a(n-1) = 4^{n-1}+a(n-1)$$

This is a nonhomogeneous linear recurrence relation which can be solved using standard techniques.  Doing so tells us that the closed form will be of the form $a(n) = c_1\cdot 4^n + c_2\cdot 1^n$ which we can solve for using the initial conditions which leads precisely to $$a(n)=\dfrac{4^n+2}{3}$$

Comment: Thank you so much